# Responsibility of Main Component and Child Component - Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, components, parent-child

I would like to ask for something about how it should look like, when we are using main(big component) and child(smallest component)

For example Main component(without htmls, it's not needed in this question)

```
export class MainComponent {
     someDto = new DtoData(); // this one contains all informations to sending data
     handleEventFromChildComponent() {//child component's output
     if(sendToApi()) == true) {
         navigateToNextStep();
     }
}

      sendToApi() {
            if(canBeSend) {
                 return someService.sendSmth(someDto)
                 .then(() => { return true; }
            }
       }

       canBeSend(): boolean {
             return complexForm.valid;
       }
}
```

Child Component(without html)

```
export class ChildComponent {
    @Output('emitter') emitter = new eventEmitter();
    saveButtonClick() {
         this.emitter.emit();
    }
}
```

My General question is that which one of these components should take responsibility for sending data to api and redirecting to next step, we have got data for dto in MainComponent.

Comment: As long as the service where the data is in own class, you can inject it into the child constructor and use it there. `constructor(someService: SomeService)`, and you have to make sure that the service has `@injectable()` decorator and is included in the providers array in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Should I use that someService in child component, even when data is on main component ? I mean every of these case works well, but I need to know which one of these components SHOULD TAKE responsibility for sending and which one for navigating.

Comment: someService is not coupled with Parent component, it should be used anywhere. As long as it's listed as a service in `app.module.ts` in the providers array.

Comment: Decouple the service as much as you can from Parent.

Comment: @CholNhial So then we will cause that child component will have informations about data, is it correct?

Comment: Yep, that's the goal of services, they are supposed to provide data to all components and are supposed to be injected through the constructor.

Comment: If I am understanding properly you could load the data from the main component and then send to child components using Input() on the child component. I generally use a container component which connects with the service then send required data to child components using [inputs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: @JesseTeWeehi I am new to angular / web front end. But I am doing in this way as well. as i am not sure injecting all the components with the service is a good idea or not. Seems it will be highly coupling the UI with a specific data provider. 

However, if i am decoupling components with service, for those nested components i have to manually pass through few layers to make the data accessible for the deepest component. 

 Not sure which way is better...